# Uploading images with laravel 5.2

Tags: php, html, forms, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to create a simple upload images function for my laravel project however I keep getting this error:

```
FatalThrowableError in UploadController.php line 23:
Fatal error: Call to a member function hasFile() on null
```

This is my controller:

```
  public function uploadImg(Request $request){
    $input = $request->input();
    if($input->hasFile('file')){
      echo 'Uploading';
      $file = $input->file('file');
      $file->move('uploads', $file->getClientOriginalName());
      echo 'Uploaded';
    }
  }
```

This is my form:

```
<form action="/admin/media/uploadImg" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label>Select image to upload:</label>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit">
    <input type="hidden" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" name="_token">
  </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `hasFile()` method only works on the request object, not the input array. Try this instead:

```
if($request->hasFile('file')){
```

See: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/requests#files

You'll also need to change this line:

```
$file = $input->file('file');
```

To:

```
$file = $request->file('file');
```